# Azure Mobile Backend first query fails

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a strange problem with the Microsoft Azure Mobile Backend for a while. Usually the first query (an automatic user check) fails at first run, after 30-60 sec of waiting it returns an error. After this error it works perfectly. I experienced this issue approximately once in a 24 hours time period.

The code is:

Step1: Initializing the backend (and after the related tables with this backend)

Backend.Primary = new Backend("https://....azurewebsites.net");

Step2: The failed query is

```
    public async Task<Tuple<Result, TeguUsers>> FindUserPC1NIC(string mac)
    {
        try
        {
            IMobileServiceTableQuery<TeguUsers> query = TeguUsersTable.Where(user => user.M1Mac1 == mac || user.M1Mac2 == mac );

            List<TeguUsers> result = await query.ToListAsync();

            return CreateFoundUsersResult(result);
        }
        catch (MobileServiceConflictException msce)
        {
            return new Tuple<Result, TeguUsers>(new Result("Failed [msce]", msce.Message), null);
        }
        catch (MobileServicePreconditionFailedException mspfe)
        {
            return new Tuple<Result, TeguUsers>(new Result("Failed [mspfe]", mspfe.Message), null);
        }
        catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException msioe)
        {
            return new Tuple<Result, TeguUsers>(new Result("Failed [msioe]", msioe.Message), null);
        }
        catch (MobileServiceODataException msode)
        {
            return new Tuple<Result, TeguUsers>(new Result("Failed [msode]", msode.Message), null);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new Tuple<Result, TeguUsers>(new Result("Failed", ex.Message), null);
        }
    }
```

Before I was using it with general Exception, today I added the specific Exceptions.

Can you tell me how to fix this problem?

- Change anything in my code?
- Change anything at backend side?
- Anything else more advanced debugging technique?

**A similar exception message is:**

Message
The request could not be completed.  (Internal Server Error)

Request
{Method: GET, RequestUri: 'https://....azurewebsites.net/tables/TeguUsers?$filter=((((((M1Mac1 eq '####') or (M1Mac2 eq '####')) or (M2Mac1 eq '####')) or (M2Mac2 eq '####')) or (M3Mac1 eq '####')) or (M3Mac2 eq '####'))&$top=1', Version: 1.1, Content: , Headers:
{
  X-ZUMO-FEATURES: TT
  X-ZUMO-INSTALLATION-ID: 7a813fc5-f5cd-47ce-97a2-9b388cb3e159
  Accept: application/json
  User-Agent: ZUMO/4.0
  User-Agent: (lang=Managed; os=Windows; os_version=6.2.0.9200; arch=Win32NT; version=4.0.1.0)
  X-ZUMO-VERSION: ZUMO/4.0 (lang=Managed; os=Windows; os_version=6.2.0.9200; arch=Win32NT; version=4.0.1.0)
  ZUMO-API-VERSION: 2.0.0
}}

Request.Header
{X-ZUMO-FEATURES: TT
X-ZUMO-INSTALLATION-ID: 7a813fc5-f5cd-47ce-97a2-9b388cb3e159
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: ZUMO/4.0 (lang=Managed; os=Windows; os_version=6.2.0.9200; arch=Win32NT; version=4.0.1.0)
X-ZUMO-VERSION: ZUMO/4.0 (lang=Managed; os=Windows; os_version=6.2.0.9200; arch=Win32NT; version=4.0.1.0)
ZUMO-API-VERSION: 2.0.0
}

Request.URI
{https://....azurewebsites.net/tables/TeguUsers?$filter=((((((M1Mac1 eq '####') or (M1Mac2 eq '####')) or (M2Mac1 eq '####')) or (M2Mac2 eq 'F0761C70A89B')) or (M3Mac1 eq '####')) or (M3Mac2 eq '####'))&$top=1}

Response
{StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Fri, 20 Oct 2017 11:14:25 GMT
  Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=3fb8a85fa49f4f848d3e147fa888c4fd566bdbdf451e7fccb0737b58d905c69c;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=....azurewebsites.net
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 0
}}

StackTrace
"   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.d__24.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.d__26.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.d__18.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable.d__20.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable.d__18.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.MobileServiceTableQueryProvider.d__8`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.MobileServiceTableQueryProvider.<Execute>d__7`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.MobileServiceTableQuery`1.<ToListAsync>d__33.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at Tegu.Azure.AMS.Table.TeguUsers.MST.d__11.MoveNext() in d:\Visual Studio Projects\TeguSolutions\TeguDev.Azure.AMS.Table.TeguUsers\Azure.AMS.Table.TeguUsers.cs:line 144"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, there is no problem with your code, but only with Azure configuration. Azure unloads your application if it's idle for a while. In most cases, it's desired behavior: you don't need to waste your Application Plan resources.

You need to take a look at **Always On** property of your Mobile App. By default, this property is set to **Off**, but you need to turn it **On**.

There are few ways to do it:

1. If you use CI/CD pipelines to maintain your app, consider ARM template for [Web Sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites). Go to *SiteConfig* object, property *alwaysOn*
2. For powershell, find an `-AppSettings` section at [official site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/Set-AzureRmWebApp?view=azurermps-5.0.0)
3. Or Azure Portal user interface. Navigate to your *App Service/Application settings*, find a **Always On** switcher.
   [image: azure_portal_sh]

**EDITED**

I suppose @Vladimir's answer explains what is happening under the hood meanwhile.

Comment: Thank you, yes you made me clear and saved me a lot of time. After 1 day of testing it looks like everything is working well.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Azure Mobile Backend used Windows hosting and IIS with all it is features - one of them is *IIS application pool recycling* - by default if Application Pool dosen`t receive an request - it unloads all resources it handle and in order to restore functionality it need abut a minute to start. In order to avoid such problem you should be able to control hosting server IIS or at least be able to run a script on it.

You need to run a script on your Web App Instance when it creates:

The default value for idle time-out is *20 minutes* - this script disable sleep mode on app pool:

```
  %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.processModel.idleTimeout:00:00:00
```

This script disable recycling mode on app pool (default *24 hours*):

```
  %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.recycling.periodicRestart.time:00:00:00
```

You also could use Remote Desktop to access instances and there in IIS Manager UI set up needed values

[Official site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/)